# Trigger Layout javascript functions to Loaded Partial View with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javaScript function that loads partial view as follows, in my page's layout:

```
$('.follow-tasks').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $followtaskList = $("#td-" + $(this).attr("data-id"));
    var t = $("#tr-" + $(this).attr("data-id"));
    t.is(":hidden") ? (t.show(),
        $followtaskList.load($followtaskList.data("url"))): t.hide();
});
```

and this  *onClick* event to show modal dialog:

```
$('.data-form').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).attr("modal-caption");
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#dataModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

When the partial view is loaded, the *onClick* event doesn't get triggered for tags that have a `.data-form` class.

How can I make the click event handler `$('.data-form').click(…)` to also handle lazy loaded partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(document).on('click','.data-form',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).attr("modal-caption");
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#dataModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

you have to bind the dynamically populated  elements to your dom